# Set dropdown selected value after loading dropdown values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, selected

I am trying to set selected value in dropdown list when the dropdown is successfully loaded.

I am loading dropdown list vaues by ajax or jQuery after that set selected value but sometime it's working fine and sometime it will not set selected the value because delay of loading dropdown. I have also tried setTimeout for that as below but it's not working properly:

```
if($("#ddlToUnit").length>0)
{     
setTimeout($("#ddlToUnit option[value='"+data.Records.GxMovement.ToUnit_v+"']").attr("selected","selected"),1000);
}
else
{ 
$("#ddlToUnit option[value='"+data.Records.GxMovement.ToUnit_v+"']").attr("selected","selected");
}
```

I want to set selected value after loading the dropdownlist...

Thanks

Comment: You need to do the default selection within the `success` callback function of your AJAX call.  That's the only way you can be sure your data is loaded, otherwise you're rolling the dice (at best).

Comment: i already used the above code in success block

Comment: What's the purpose of the if statement, and, why would `$("#ddlToUnit").length` not always be 1?

Comment: in if statement i am checking that the dropdown list length is equal to 0 or it's not bind any value. i have mistakenly write greater than sign instead of equal to

Comment: To count the list for this purpose, you'd probably want to use `$("#ddlToUnit option")`, but of course there must be a better way than arbitrarily waiting a second.  So I guess my question is, how is it possible for this list to be empty if this is in the callback function?  I'd need to see more code.  Are you populating the list separately and asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, this is an edit form functionaity where we bind or load dropdown list asynchronously seperately in top of edit form and after some other functions we are trying to set selected this dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you can use `setInterval` to keep checking whether the elements have been populated yet.  The first `setTimeout` function is just simulating taking 3 seconds to add an option to a list.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var newOption = document.createElement('option');
  newOption.innerHTML = 'Option Text';
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(newOption);
}, 3000);

// Do something only after list is populated
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (document.querySelectorAll('#list option').length > 0) {
    console.log('List is definitely populated!');
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 200);
```

```html
<select id="list">
</select>
```

Comment: thanks @snapjs it is working but sometime `document.querySelectorAll('#list option').length` returns 1...

Comment: Well, one other solution you could pursue is having a variable that gets set to true only when all the data you need is totally loaded

Comment: but dropdown list bind data dynamically and i don't know the list count

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the code that binds the list data, otherwise it's really hard to know what exactly might indicate completion of list element binding.